# How to enable gzip .js with ?ver in .htaccess?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, gzip

I have .htaccess with following code

```
AddType text/javascript .js
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript text/javascript application/x-javascript
```

But Google PageSpeed Insights still telling me, that all of my .js?ver= files is not compressed. I have checked this files with firebug and yes, content-type is "application/javascript", but compression is not working. However, gzip work for css/text/etc.

Help me find out, please.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, assuming `mod_headers` is enabled:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]
  RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]
  <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz)$">
    Header set Content-Encoding gzip
    Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```